Is it possible to update state in LaunchedEffect without Unsupported Concurrent change problem?
I've got ErrorScreen which is an overlay on my every screen. It collects errors from Flow. It has own errorState.
I'm not sure, but is it a proper way to handle this state and update?
From my understanding I collect flow in different thread, then update state in it, but at the same time I could have recompositions of my screen. Couldn't it provide to Unsupported concurrent change errors, which I have in my application? What is a proper way to handle it?
@Composable
fun ErrorQueueScreen(
    queue: Flow<ErrorQueueModel?>
) {

   val errorState = remember { mutableStateOf<QueueScreenState>(QueueScreenState.NoError) }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect("QueueScreenCollector") {
        queue.distinctUntilChanged().collectLatest {
            val state = it?.let { QueueScreenState.Error(it) } ?: QueueScreenState.NoError
            errorState.value = state
        }
    }

    errorState.value.run {
        if (this is QueueScreenState.Error) {
            if (this.errorItem.exception.toDisplayableTitle(context) == context.getString(R.string.error_weight_limit_title)) {
                onSendCartIsHeavyEvent.invoke()
            }
    
           }

            ErrorDialog(
                
            ) {
                
            }
        }
    }
}



It is better you use state of  ErrorQueueModel that is update in your view model.




OK, got it. I need to rethink that but it should be possible. I have for example HomeScreenNav class where I create navigation and my initialize my screen and here I could have 2 viewmodels, viewmodel for ErrorScreen and Viewmodel for HomeScreen. In my case it is not that simple as in yours, I have ErrorScreen as overlay on HomeScreen, I need to handle it in viewmodel that's true. Why do you think it is better way, do you think my code in that manner could provide to unconcurrent change error?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
